# Guardar texto en un ArrayList para ver palabras repetidas

Tags: arraylist, contador

Tengo el siguiente código el cual debería ingresar un texto, descomponerlo por palabras y guardarlo en un ArrayList para despúes evaluar esa arraylist consigo mismae identificar el número de palabras que se repiten, el problema es que unicamente toma y evalua la primer palabra del texto que ingresen, no encuentro una forma para lograr que el programa cuente las otras palabras de mi texto. alguien me puede ayudar por favor??

el resultado tiene que ser cuales palabras se repiten y la cantidad de veces que se repiten, o en el caso del siguiente texto descompone todo en palabras, las separa e indica cuantas veces se repite cada una pero no logro pasar de la primer palabra.

```
package contadorpalabras;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ContadorPalabras {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new  InputStreamReader(System.in));
    ArrayList <String> palabras = new ArrayList<>();

    String cadena[] = reader.readLine().split(" ");
    palabras.addAll(Arrays.asList(cadena));
    for (String palabra : palabras){
    System.out.println(palabra);    
    }


    for (String palabra : cadena) {
        String minus = palabra.toLowerCase();
        int contador =0;
        if (!palabras.contains(minus)){
            for (String demas : cadena){
                if (demas.toLowerCase().equals(minus)){
                    contador++;
                }
            }
            palabras.add(minus);


                    System.out.println(minus+": "+contador+((contador == 1)?" vez":" veces"));   
        }   
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Acá está completo el código, la clave está en utilizar un HashMap que guarda llaves únicas y va haciendo el conteo de las ocurrencias de las palabras.

**yo fui quien respondió tu post anterior, a la próxima comenta el fallo antes de votar negativo por favor, te hubiese ayudado más fácilmente así**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    ArrayList<String> palabras = new ArrayList<>(); 

    String cadena[] = reader.readLine().split(" ");
    palabras.addAll(Arrays.asList(cadena));

    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    for (String palabra : palabras) {
      if (map.containsKey(palabra)) {
        map.put(palabra, map.get(palabra) + 1);
      } else {
        map.put(palabra, 1);
      }
    }

    for (String palabra : map.keySet()) {
      System.out.println(palabra + " " + map.get(palabra));
    }
  }
}
```